# Can't get the RegEx right

Tags: javascript, html, regex

The function checks out and everything works, I'm really just having trouble getting a pattern search that fits what I want. I'm trying to get a handle on RegEx's but they're a bit confusing to be honest. I'm trying to make it so the user's input is only accepted if it's a capital letter followed by lowercase letters, to maximum of ten letters and minimum of three. Can anyone give me a RegEx that fits this?

```
$("#name").blur(function() {
    var pattern = /^[A-Z]+[a-z]$/;
    if (document.account.name.value.search(pattern) == -1) {
        $("#namemessage").text("Name must be a single capitalized word with no special characters");
        nameerror = 1;
    }
    else {
        $("#namemessage").text("");
        nameerror = 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
/^[A-Z][a-z]{2,9}$/
```

In English: capital letter, followed by 2 to 9 lowercase letters.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! I'm gonna have to get used to this pattern format, I didn't even use the + right, lol.